# API Authentication with active Session

Tags: javascript, html, cookies, session-cookies

Currently I am trying to trigger an Event within MicroStrategy.
Unfortunately the Webinterface does not support that but the API does and the Enduser can‘t use any other MicroStrategy Tool.

So my solution to that Problem would be to call the API via JavaScript inside a HTML container of a Dossier.
The Problem is that i can‘t authenticate myself without having my password in clear text what is a no go to me.

The thing is, the [API Playground](https://demo.microstrategy.com/MicroStrategyLibrary/api-docs/index.html) is automatically authenticated if you are logged in, so one of my questions is how does the playground authenticate itself?

And with the GET Token method your are able to connect via existing cookies. I can find those in my browser but the one needed (Session ID) is html only so I can‘t read nor pass it further.

Is there a way to connect without other MicroStrategy Tools or having to save your password somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

You could create a PHP file with the API key stored in it and fetch that and then send your request to MicroStrategy. But you do have to realize that even if you do add restrictions on who can view the PHP file and have finally finished that, the requests can be viewed via the network tab in developer tools. Nothing can be hided due to it being client-side.

```
//Example code
fetch('/php_file.php')then(response => response.json()).then(data => {
      console.log(data);
      //Send GET request using data as API key
}).catch(error => console.error(error));
```